# Using multiple conditions within an if statement

Tags: javascript

How using multiple conditions within an if statement?

```js
function testNum(a) {
  if (a == (1 || 2 || 3)) {
    return "is 1, 2, or 3";
  } else {
    return "is not 1, 2, or 3";
  }
}

console.log(testNum(1)); // returns "is 1, 2, or 3"
console.log(testNum(2)); // returns "is not 1, 2, or 3"
console.log(testNum(3)); // returns "is not 1, 2, or 3"
```

`testNum(2)` and `testNum(3)` should `return: "is 1, 2 or 3"` but doesn't.

Comment: (a == (1 || 2 || 3)) is invalid syntax

Comment: @KevinVandy How is that? No syntax errors in the code.

Comment: @KevinVandy It's not at all (see my answer)!

Comment: @Teemu Ok, correction, it is misleading syntax

Comment: @KevinVandy it is a logical error, not a syntax error.

Comment: None of the answers have touched on it but @SkyRedTea the problem is that javascript supports truthy/falsey comparisons. 1, 2, and 3 are truthy. So `1 || 2 || 3` is the same as `true` Your logic is checking `if (a == true)`

Comment: @Marie Nope, it always checks `a == 1`. JS logical OR operator returns an operand, not a boolean.

Comment: @Teemu Yessss finally someone knows the way!

Answer (score 8):

In this particular scenario, you can even use an array and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method for checking.

```
if ([1, 2, 3].includes(a)) {
  // your code
}
```

```js
function testNum(a) {
  if ([1, 2, 3].includes(a)) {
    return "is 1, 2, or 3";
  } else {
    return "is not 1, 2, or 3";
  }
}
console.log(testNum(1));
console.log(testNum(2));
console.log(testNum(4));
console.log(testNum(3));
```

---

**FYI :** In your current code `(1 || 2 || 3)` results `1`(since 1 is truthy) and actually `a == (1 || 2 || 3)` does `a == 1`. The right way is to seperate each conditions with `||` (or),  *for eg :* `a == 1 || a == 2 || a ==3`.

For more details visit [MDN documentation of Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: One of the best one-liners.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have `||` like that. The one you have used is not the right way. You should be using:

```js
function testNum(a) {
  if (a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3) {
    return "is 1, 2, or 3";
  } else {
    return "is not 1, 2, or 3";
  }
}

console.log(testNum(1));
console.log(testNum(2));
console.log(testNum(3));
```

Comment: You can have `||` like that, it just does not do what the OP assumed it did. I think you should clarify what it WAS doing.

Comment: @Marie See my answer :)

Comment: @Marie I guess Pranav explains it perfectly... 

Answer (score 4):

Your or-operators are placed incorrectly:

```
function testNum(a) {
    if (a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3) {
        return "is 1, 2, or 3";
    } else {
        return "is not 1, 2, or 3";
    }
}
```

Before, you were testing if `a` was equal to `1 || 2 || 3` which evaluates to `1` †. So you were just checking `a == 1` which is not what you wanted!

† Essentially when you string together "or"s like this, the first truthy value is returned. For example, you can assert for yourself that: `0 || False || 5` gives `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a list of qualified values and check if the lookup value belongs there:

```
function testNum(a) {
    var candidates = [1, 2, 3];
    if (candidates.indexOf(a) != -1) {
        return "is 1, 2, or 3";
    } else {
        return "is not 1, 2, or 3";
    }
}

console.log(testNum(1)); // returns "is 1, 2, or 3"
console.log(testNum(2)); // returns "is not 1, 2, or 3"
console.log(testNum(3));
console.log(testNum(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either

```
    if (a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3) {
```

or

```
    if ([1, 2, 3].includes(a)) {
```

which will be more convenient when there's more values to test. If you want to be compatible with ancient browsers, you have to write it like this

```
    if ([1, 2, 3].indexOf(a) >= 0) {
```

which look undeniably uglier.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not getting the expected result because you are performing a Logical OR operation here.

As per MDN Network :
Logical OR (||) expr1 || expr2  If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr1; else, returns expr2.

(1 || 2 || 3) is evaluated and the operation results at 1. You can check the result by pasting `(1 || 2 || 3)` in Chrome debugger or something.

So when the first number is 1 in all cases, the expression result is also 1. You can change the expression as how others have advised to get the desired output.